# Cocoa/MacRuby: How to write a toolbar which accepts custom items?

Tags: ruby, cocoa, delegates, macruby

I'm doing my first steps in MacRuby. Does anyone know how I can add a custom Toolbar to my Cocoa/MacRuby application, which will accept "regular" items for e.g. switching the view (see http://www.stevestreeting.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/SelectableToolbarDemo001.png).

I've read some tutorials and I guess I have to create a custom delegate for the Toolbar and then connect it via the Outlets window, but how does the myCustomDelegate.rb have to look like?

Comment: In case you're still interested in a pure MacRuby implementation of this, [gmail notifr](https://github.com/ashchan/gmail-notifr) has a preferences windows with toolbar and two views.

Comment: Cool, great example with lots of goodies. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent tutorial here: http://www.mere-mortal-software.com/blog/details.php?d=2007-03-14

It is targeted at preferences windows, but of course you could use the window class anywhere.

I have not bothered to port the window superclass to Macruby, I just use it as is. Then I use macruby to write the subclass, for example:

```
class MopenPrefsWindowController < DBPrefsWindowController
  attr_accessor :generalPrefsView
  attr_accessor :openingPrefsView
  attr_accessor :advancedPrefsView
  attr_accessor :appearancePrefsView  

  def setupToolbar
    self.addView(generalPrefsView, label:"General", image:NSImage.imageNamed(NSImageNamePreferencesGeneral))
    self.addView(openingPrefsView, label:"Opening")
    self.addView(advancedPrefsView, label:"Advanced", image:NSImage.imageNamed(NSImageNameAdvanced))
    self.addView(appearancePrefsView, label:"Appearance")
  end
end
```

The one thing that might cause me to some day port the window class to macruby is to give it the ability to have a bottom section that appears on all panes.